# Access ResourceBundle keys which contain dots ?

Tags: jsf, jsf-2, el

My JSF2 application is fully internationalized, using a ResourceBundle.

Now i have a lot of Javascript-code, which does some alerts and stuff. There i would like to access my ResourceBundle. I could successfully access simple ResourceBundle keys like this:

```
alert("#{bundle.message_email_sent}");
```

Unfortunately, my convention for keys in my bundle is to use dots **.** as seperators for my keys, for example `message.email.sent=E-Mails sent.`. But when i do

```
alert("#{bundle.message.email.sent}");
```

JSF tries to access "email" like a function on the string returned by bundle.message. 
How can i tell the EL-resolver to use the whole "message.email.sent" as the key?

I also tried stuff like

```
alert("#{bundle[\'message.email.sent\']}");
```

Which also results in errors.
Any suggestions?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You indeed need to use the brace notation, when the 'key' contains characters that have a meaning in EL, but you don't need to escape the singlequotes, regardless of whatever JS syntax highlighter is telling you otherwise. EL runs when Java/JSF runs, not when JS runs.

```
alert("#{bundle['message.email.sent']}");
```

Comment: So obvious... why didn't i test that? Thanks!